# Spring AMQP Error: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have classes:

```
public class MqMessage implements Serializable{
    private String event;
    private String absolutePath;
    private boolean isDirectory;
    private Integer hash;
    private Node node;

    get/set

}
```

Configuration class:
public class RabbitConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    template.setExchange("exchange-events");
    return template;
}

//объявляем очередь
@Bean
public Queue myQueue1() {
    return new Queue("queue-events");
}

@Bean
public FanoutExchange fanoutExchangeA() {
    return new FanoutExchange("exchange-events");
}

@Bean
public Binding binding1() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(myQueue1()).to(fanoutExchangeA());
}
```

Send message

```
    public class ServerHandler implements EventHandler {

        //сама структура отражающая состояние файлов, содеражащая метоы для работы с ними
        @Autowired
        Node fileTreeRoot;

        SimpleMessageConverter simpleMessageConverter;

        @Override
        public void setRoot(Node fileTreeRoot) {
            this.fileTreeRoot = fileTreeRoot;
        }
        @Autowired
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

        //логика обработки событий
        @Override
        public void eventHandle(String event, String path) {

            /*bussines-logick
*/
            rabbitTemplate.setExchange("exchange-events");

            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(new MqMessage(event,fileTreeRoot));
            return;
        }

        public ServerHandler() {

    }
```

Listener:

```
public class Client {
Node rootNodeClient = new Node();
EventHandler handlerClient = new ClientHandler();


@RabbitListener(queues = "queue-events")
public void onMessage(MqMessage message) {
    System.out.println(message.getNode().hashCode());
    rootNodeClient = message.getNode();
}
```

a have error only start app

> 2017-08-08 12:58:02.128  WARN 5024 --- [cTaskExecutor-1]
>   s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message
>   listener failed.
>
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException:
>   Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException:
>   Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void
>   prcjt.client.Client.onMessage(prcjt.message.MqMessage): 1 error(s):
>   [Error in object 'message': codes []; arguments []; default message
>   [Payload value must not be empty]]

Error does not always exist
Help please

Answer (score 4):

Using `mappingJackson2MessageConverted` did not work for me. After lots of investigation found that I was using wrong converter. Add the below code in Listener service, it worked for me.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0
```

From the exception information, it seems that spring could not resolve `MqMessage` in the listener correctly, you can try to add a `mappingJackson2MessageConverter` to the client. Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770725/spring-boot-rabbitmq-mappingjackson2messageconverter-custom-object-conversion/30786059#30786059).

Comment: I think the story is exactly opposite- `Payload value must not be empty`. That means the converted is configured for the listener container can't properly deserialize the body. Looks like the `RabbitTemplate` uses the default `SimpleMessageConverter` and serialize `MqMessage` using standard JAva serialization, but container factory is based on some other converter, maybe even that mentioned `mappingJackson2MessageConverter`. You definitely should use the same converter on the consumer side

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue for couple of reasons:

1. Not using "implements Serializable" (which I see you are already using)
2. No constructor in model class. (Use empty constructor)

   ```
   public ClassToGetQData() {
       super();
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
   ```

Also, using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` helped me with missing data elements in incoming data.